Calculate median by groups based on two columns and by the occurance of an id
I'm trying to find a solution in base R that can calculate the median by groups based on two columns in addition to groups by the occurrence of multiple ids.
For example:
I have a data.frame
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20), 
                group = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                num = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
                value = c(sample(10:90, 16, replace = TRUE), rep(c(21,67,80,69), times=1, each=2)))


> df
   id group num value
1   1     A 0.1    59
2   2     A 0.1    72
3   3     A 0.1    82
4   4     A 0.1    17
5   5     A 0.2    39
6   6     A 0.2    46
7   7     A 0.2    39
8   8     A 0.2    56
9   9     B 0.1    31
10 10     B 0.1    46
11 11     B 0.1    63
12 12     B 0.1    15
13 13     C 0.1    51
14 14     C 0.1    68
15 15     C 0.1    48
16 16     C 0.1    28
17 17     A 0.1    21
18 17     B 0.1    21
19 18     A 0.1    67
20 18     B 0.1    67
21 19     A 0.1    80
22 19     B 0.1    80
23 20     A 0.1    69
24 20     B 0.1    69

and I'm trying to replace the values in the column value by the median based on groups from the columns group and num, meaning I want the median for the group A 0.1, A 0.2, B 0.1, C 0.1 and now to the tricky part, in which additionally values are grouped based on multiple occurrences of the id, in that case id 17, 18, 19 and 20 belong to the same group AB 0.1.
This should lead to a result with the following df:
> df
   id group num value
1   1     A 0.1    65.5
2   2     A 0.1    65.5
3   3     A 0.1    65.5
4   4     A 0.1    65.5

5   5     A 0.2    42.5
6   6     A 0.2    42.5
7   7     A 0.2    42.5
8   8     A 0.2    42.5

9   9     B 0.1    38.5
10 10     B 0.1    38.5
11 11     B 0.1    38.5
12 12     B 0.1    38.5

13 13     C 0.1    49.5
14 14     C 0.1    49.5
15 15     C 0.1    49.5
16 16     C 0.1    49.5

17 17     A 0.1    68.0
18 17     B 0.1    68.0
19 18     A 0.1    68.0
20 18     B 0.1    68.0
21 19     A 0.1    68.0
22 19     B 0.1    68.0
23 20     A 0.1    68.0
24 20     B 0.1    68.0

How can this be accomplished with base R without writing a function? Could this even be done in an one-liner?

First create an additional group by pasting group by id then split twice by the new group and num.
grp <- unlist(sapply(split(df, df$id), \(x) 
                cbind(x, grp = paste(x$group, collapse=""))$grp))

data.frame(do.call(rbind,
  lapply(split(df, grp), \(x)
    do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x$num), \(y)
      cbind(y[,-4], value = median(y$value)))))),
  row.names=NULL)
   id group num value
1   1     A 0.1  45.5
2   2     A 0.1  45.5
3   3     A 0.1  45.5
4   4     A 0.1  45.5
5   5     A 0.2  56.0
6   6     A 0.2  56.0
7   7     A 0.2  56.0
8   8     A 0.2  56.0
9  17     A 0.1  68.0
10 17     B 0.1  68.0
11 18     A 0.1  68.0
12 18     B 0.1  68.0
13 19     A 0.1  68.0
14 19     B 0.1  68.0
15 20     A 0.1  68.0
16 20     B 0.1  68.0
17  9     B 0.1  46.5
18 10     B 0.1  46.5
19 11     B 0.1  46.5
20 12     B 0.1  46.5
21 13     C 0.1  64.0
22 14     C 0.1  64.0
23 15     C 0.1  64.0
24 16     C 0.1  64.0

Data
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20),
  group = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
  num = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
  value = c(sample(10:90, 16, replace = TRUE), rep(c(21,67,80,69), times=1, each=2)))


Thanks. Could you post the result for grp? I get NULL as a result. Did you meant to write cbind(x, paste(x$group, collapse=""))$ group ? In that case, unlist creates unique names for ids that come in pairs, for example, the pair with the id 18, is unlisted to 181 and 182.

@SchlaWiener Sry, that must have been a cp/paste error, it was missing the name. Should work now.

Here is one way to achieve this in base R.
We create a new grouping variable (new_group) according to our conditions. Using duplicated twice we identify the id's that repeat and assign them a random grouping number (here I have assigned 999) for the rest we create a sequential grouping number based on their occurrence using match and unique.
After this grouping variable is created we can use ave to calculate median per group.
val <- paste(df$group, df$num, sep = "-")

df |>
  transform(new_group = ifelse(duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE), 
                               999, match(val, unique(val)))) |>
  transform(value = ave(value, new_group, FUN = median))

#   id group num value new_group
#1   1     A 0.1  65.5         1
#2   2     A 0.1  65.5         1
#3   3     A 0.1  65.5         1
#4   4     A 0.1  65.5         1
#5   5     A 0.2  42.5         2
#6   6     A 0.2  42.5         2
#7   7     A 0.2  42.5         2
#8   8     A 0.2  42.5         2
#9   9     B 0.1  38.5         3
#10 10     B 0.1  38.5         3
#11 11     B 0.1  38.5         3
#12 12     B 0.1  38.5         3
#13 13     C 0.1  49.5         4
#14 14     C 0.1  49.5         4
#15 15     C 0.1  49.5         4
#16 16     C 0.1  49.5         4
#17 17     A 0.1  68.0       999
#18 17     B 0.1  68.0       999
#19 18     A 0.1  68.0       999
#20 18     B 0.1  68.0       999
#21 19     A 0.1  68.0       999
#22 19     B 0.1  68.0       999
#23 20     A 0.1  68.0       999
#24 20     B 0.1  68.0       999

I have purposefully kept the new_group column so as to understand how the groups were created. If the column is not needed you may add |> subset(select = -new_group) to the pipe.

A one-liner (if you don't consider adding a new column part of the code)
> df$newid=ave(df$id,list(df$group,df$num),FUN=min)
> df[ave(df$id,df$id,FUN=length)>1,"newid"]=999
> df$value=ave(df$value,df$newid,FUN=median)

   id group num value newid
1   1     A 0.1  71.0     1
2   2     A 0.1  71.0     1
3   3     A 0.1  71.0     1
4   4     A 0.1  71.0     1
5   5     A 0.2  32.0     5
6   6     A 0.2  32.0     5
7   7     A 0.2  32.0     5
8   8     A 0.2  32.0     5
9   9     B 0.1  32.5     9
10 10     B 0.1  32.5     9
11 11     B 0.1  32.5     9
12 12     B 0.1  32.5     9
13 13     C 0.1  58.5    13
14 14     C 0.1  58.5    13
15 15     C 0.1  58.5    13
16 16     C 0.1  58.5    13
17 17     A 0.1  68.0   999
18 17     B 0.1  68.0   999
19 18     A 0.1  68.0   999
20 18     B 0.1  68.0   999
21 19     A 0.1  68.0   999
22 19     B 0.1  68.0   999
23 20     A 0.1  68.0   999
24 20     B 0.1  68.0   999

Note that my results are different than yours since you generate the data randomly without a seed.

Thanks. This works for that example, but would not work, if there's more than one occurrence of multiple ids, for example AB 0.1 and AC 0.1. I haven't used more multiple pairs of group to keep it simple, but now I see that I should have done it.

@SchlaWiener I don't think I understand, can you update your question with such an example and desired output?

I might update the question later by extending it with a new set of numbers, basically continuing id in pairs 21,21,22,22,23,23,24,24, the group with A,C,A,C,A,C,A,C, num with 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1 and random values. This would based on your code also have a newid of 999, although it is a new group of pairs: AC. It should have a unique newid, like 998 for example. Hope that made sense.
